# Fastest way to level up a griffin

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-skyblock

I play hypixel skyblock and I have a griffin pet at level 35. Before I started blindly grinding kills, I wanted to know what is the most efficient method to do this.

I have unlocked 10 minion slots and I have full ender armor with a raiders axe, if it helps.

The Griffin Pet is a Combat Pet that can be obtained from the NPC Diana. The pet is not required to spawn Mythological Creatures, but it scales their difficulty with its Rarity. The Griffin Pet is considered a good early to mid game Damage dealing pet due to its high damage stats and the Legendary Constitution perk that gives the player high level potion effects.
You can find more info on this pet at [this hypixel skyblock wiki page](https://hypixel-skyblock.fandom.com/wiki/Griffin_Pet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Experiments

The experimentation table is one of the best sources of xp in the game. You can get millions of xp per day, the downside is it can only give enchanting xp, which means your griffin wont level up as fast as if you got combat xp, but it still helps a lot, its how i got my giffin to level 75. As a bonus, you can get xp bottles (all types) and enchanted books including tier 6 and 7 books (which are often worth millions).

### Plain old grinding

Drink a combat xp boost (obtainable from gifts) and start grinding, I would recommend the end (crypts if you want to get rev slayer up).